# How insert multiple columns into two columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

```
date1      amt1  date2      amt2 date3       amt3 (and so on till date50 amt50)
2010-01-18 400   2010-01-19 200  2010-01-30  600
2010-01-19 1200  2010-01-21 400  2010-01-23  1000

(more than 9,000 rows below)
```

Convert into format below:

```
date          amt
2010-01-18    400
2010-01-19    200
2010-01-30    600
2010-01-19    1200
2010-01-21    400
2010-01-23    1000

(and so on)
```

[image: This is screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried the parse function in excel? Perhaps consider replacing multiple spaces to one or even commas first.

Comment: @SolarMike No. Can you explain more about how can I use parsing function to work on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution just now!! I have to change in bulks but it did speed up my work.

I use Transform Range in KuTools. First I select "Range to single column" option, so all columns are inside 1 column now.
Then, I select that one column, and use "Single Column to Range". And a trick here for me, set Fixed Value to 2 so the ranges are inserted into 2 columns.
And it works.

[Step 1: Transform Range: **Range to Single Column**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4egzl.png)

[Step 2: Transform Range: **Single Column to Range** and Set **Fixed Value to "2"**(columns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIqwK.png)

Comment: Anyway, should I keep or delete this question? I think it is a not so useful question.

Comment: Keep the question, may well help someone and that is the point.

Comment: @SolarMike Ok I will keep. Thanks.